# Bank Letter or Bank Statements

Tags: visas, canada, proof-provenance-of-funds

One quick question. I plan on getting a bank letter for my Canadian visa (Temporary resident visa) application and the question I would like to ask is quite simple.

Can I present a bank Letter in place of my bank statements? which details that I have certain Funds in my bank account? Kindly let me know as soon as possible.

Comment: Bank statements are far superior. A bank statement shows the pattern of your withdrawals and deposits which is more than a bank letter which will not show those details. Why do you want to show a bank letter? That’s unusual

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) (Which is officially about the UK but the answer applies to Canada as well).